# plink doesn't generate a sexcheck-file

Tags: plink

I was executing the following command `plink.exe --file GWAS --check-sex --noweb`
Expecthing to get a `plink.sexcheck` file but I don't get anything. Not even an error. The output is always:

```
Skipping web check... [ --noweb ]
Writing this text to log file [ plink.log ]
Analysis started: Sat Mar 13 12:24:18 2021

Options in effect:
        --file GWAS
        --check-sex
        --noweb

75 (of 75) markers to be included from [ GWAS.map ]
```

Do you know what could be the issue there? I have a `GWAS.map` and `GWAS.ped` file. Do I need any additional information for this to work?